# Is it possible to 'chain' multiple test suites from the Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a group that has some non-technical people creating tests and test suites using the Selenium IDE.  I'd like for that group to be able to work independently, yet after the fact be able to run a series of those suites with minimal button clicks.  There are a lot of reasons why I'm not just writing tests using some 'native' language (groovy or java) and making this easy to use for the team will help adoption of testing.

So, I would like to be able to just instruct the members of the team to open a single 'suite' (or equivalent) and run it and it would then run each of the suites that I have designated as part of the 'master suite' (if you follow me).

I know that I could just maintain a list of the suites that are part of our automated tests, but it would be easier for me to sell if it was possible to just open up a single file and click 'go' and then walk away and see the results after coming back from getting a cup of coffee or something.

Answer (score 1):

If your reason for not going with a native language is because of your non-technical people, then your automation strategy will fail.

Sorry for being blunt, but there is a reason why there is the IDE, and there is the native language support.  They both serve very different purpose, and if you don't approach automation with the respect that it's a programming exercise, then your automation strategy will fail.

Selenium IDE is extremely limited.  You are unable to string multiple test suites together.  You only have the option of creating one huge a** list of test cases in one suite, or loading your suites in one at a time.

Go WebDriver - everything that you want to do, is extremely limited, if even possible using the IDE.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, [I wrote a framework that does that](https://github.com/djangofan/simple-selenium-builder-framework).   You can record as many "[Selenium Builder](https://saucelabs.com/builder)" scripts as you like and they will be ran by my framework in a multi-threaded fashion as a group.  Just fork your own copy of my framework and then modify it to your uses.